# HTML/Javascript/Bootstrap cannot hide button when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have this code, I am trying to make the login/register buttons to hide the buttons once clicked, they instead flash (hide and quickly come back).

I am new to web development in general so I may be doing something stupid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Login.css" />

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <!--Login/Register Tabs-->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#loginTab">Login</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#registerTab">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--Tabs Content-->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="loginTab" class="tab-pane active">
                <form>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input id="loginUsernameText" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input id="loginPasswordText" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button id="loginButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="registerTab" class="tab-pane fade">
                <form>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input id="registerUsernameText" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username (3-24 Char)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input id="registerPasswordText" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password (3-24 Char)">
                    </div>
                    <button id="registerButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src="Login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Login.js written with jquery

```
$('#loginButton').click(function () {
    $('#loginButton').addClass('hidden');
    $('#registerButton').addClass('hidden');
});

$('#registerButton').click(function () {
    $('#loginButton').addClass('hidden');
    $('#registerButton').addClass('hidden');
});
```

### Any help is appreciated

SOLVED: settings attribute type="button" for the buttons saved my life, thanks for help!

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following :

1) Add type="button" attributes to your buttons, might save you from some cases where buttons in form act as submits unless stated as of type=button.

2) Rewrite to the following

```
var registerButton = $('#registerButton');
var loginButton= $('#loginButton');

function hideButtons(){
    registerButton.hide(); // or add your custom class here
    loginButton.hide();    // or add your custom class here
    return false;          // avoid bubling
}

loginButton.on('click',function () {
    hideButtons();
});

registerButton.on('click',function () {
   hideButtons();
});
```

Tell me if it worked

Comment: OMG Man you've saved my life as I have been searching for hours thank you very much works perfectly now